# how to shuffle items of a list using python?

Tags: python, list

I want to riffle shuffle items of a list without necessary importing any module.
So a function should return a riffle shuffled list, riffle shuffle is where it will first break it into two lists then interleave them into one list.

for example
the list= [ a, b ,c ,d]

should be
[ c,a,d,b] or [a, c,b,d] after riffle shuffling it

Comment: Python requires importing the `random` module if you want to do anything random.

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to import *anything*? Just no 3th party packages or also no python supplies packages?

Comment: @InbarRose, There is also `os.urandom` for random bytes suitable for cryptographic use.

Comment: @gnibbler: yes, but if you cant import os....

Comment: @RickyA, I didn't need to import anything

Comment: @gnibbler: then try run it. You do need to `import os`.

Comment: You should not be afraid to import modules and use them. It's like not ever being able to change your clothes because it requires opening the closet, the closet is there to keep your clothes when you don't wear them so you don't need to carry them around with you all the time. Much like the modules require importing so that not every small script is lugging around a massive closet full of clothing (or modules in this case).

Answer (score 3):

## Python2 version

```
cards = range(52)
a = cards[:len(cards)/2]
b = cards[len(cards)/2:]
if id('')/0xffff&1:
    a, b = b, a
cards[::2] = a
cards[1::2] = b
print cards
```

## Python3 version

```
cards = list(range(52))
a = cards[:len(cards)//2]
b = cards[len(cards)//2:]
if id('')//0xffff&1:
    a, b = b, a
cards[::2] = a
cards[1::2] = b
print(cards)
```

Comment: But here you don't import anything :)

Comment: But - here the riffle is set from the start, the idea is that on each pair there is a 50/50 chance that one will be above the other.

Comment: @InbarRose, I agree that sounds sensible, but that doesn't match the two possible outcomes given in the question.

Comment: That is beside the point, the explanation given makes it clear that each 2 items should be randomized.

Comment: So why not [a,c,d,b] or [c,a,b,d]?

Comment: Ask the OP why he did not include those examples.

Comment: The question just says the first item is randomly chosen. I assumed it's some sort of simplified version of a shuffle for learning purpose (especially given the "no imports" criteria)

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the Python 3 version of this code will work just fine in Python 2 as well. The `//` floor division operator was implemented for Python 2.2 way back in 2001. The `list` call around range, and the parentheses around the single argument to `print` are harmless in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is fun! No imports!

The problem is that we need a coin flip without importing anything. Sounds like a test for `<some random int> % 2 == 0`. The hard part is `<some random int>`. A pointer on the heap maybe?

```
input_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

#you should empty this once and awhile
fill_my_heap = [] 

#nothing to see here
class Dummy(): 
    pass

for x in range(0,10):    
    #give me a new pointer
    foo = Dummy()
    #prevent reuse of heap memory location
    fill_my_heap.append(foo) 
    #get id of new class and strip its last digit because that was always even
    ptr_int = int(str(id(foo))[:-1]) 
    #test to see if this is even. Should be 50% of the time. Sort of... ;)
    is_even = ptr_int%2==0 
    #split list
    a = input_list[:len(input_list)/2]
    b = input_list[len(input_list)/2:]
    #and assemble output based on even-switch
    if is_even:
        output = a + b
    else:
        output = b + a
    print(output)
```

Gives:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: `id(foo)` will give you the memory location, without the string manipulation.

Comment: @Blckknght: forgot about that one :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like imports, a simple [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is pretty straightforward to code:

```
def lcg(_):
    lcg.val = (1664525 * lcg.val + 1013904223) & 0xffffffff
    return lcg.val

lcg.val = id('') # seed
```

and then:

```
print sorted(range(52), key=lcg)
```